# Serialize object with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml

I need to serialize an object using datacontract serializer.
The problem is that i haven't the object data in a stream or one string. I have an XmlElement with the xml contents.

I want to do:

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(Xpto.GetType());
XmlReader = ... //i need the create an XmlReader (or XmlDictionaryReader) from a XmlElement (or XmlDocument)
Xpto x = (Xpto)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
```

Any ideia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`XmlNodeReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader.aspx) to process an `XmlElement` object:

```
XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(myElement);
```